You cant deploy a angular app that has Internationalization on a deployment platform
I am unable to deploy the application after adding Internationalization and tried to configure the deployment to go to the corresponding dist folder outputs for those however it doesn't seem to work
Here is my angular.json:
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "PCMS.FrontEnd": {
      "i18n": {
        "sourceLocale": "en-US",
        "locales": {
          "cy": {
            "translation": "src/locale/messages.cy.xlf",
             "baseHref": "cy"
          }
        }
      },
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "standalone": true,
          "style": "scss"
        },
        "@schematics/angular:directive": {
          "standalone": false
        },
        "@schematics/angular:pipe": {
          "standalone": false
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:application",
          "options": {
            "localize": ["cy"],
            "outputPath": "dist",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "browser": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": ["zone.js"],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "public"
              }
            ],
            "styles": [
              "@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/azure-blue.css",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "cy": {
              "localize": ["cy"]
            },
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kB",
                  "maximumError": "1MB"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kB",
                  "maximumError": "4kB"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ]
            },
            "development": {
              "optimization": false,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "cy": {
              "buildTarget": "PCMS.FrontEnd:build:development,fr"
            },
            "production": {
              "buildTarget": "PCMS.FrontEnd:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildTarget": "PCMS.FrontEnd:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n"
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "polyfills": ["zone.js", "zone.js/testing"],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "assets": [
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "public"
              }
            ],
            "styles": [
              "@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/azure-blue.css",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "standalone": true,
      "style": "scss"
    }
  },
  "cli": {
    "analytics": false
  }
}


i can see it on local development when i run ng serve and can see the welsh translations ive made but i dont know how it would be on a productio0n deployment
I tried pointing the output path on some deployment platforms to point to dist then dist/browser/cy or en-us but none of these deploy the app and fail, as well as trying to navigate to /cy in the url to see it, i tried deploying on vercel and netlify with the build command ng build --localize  and pointing the output path to dist
